# JavaFX 8 (JRE8) ComboBox shows scrollbars on first click if even dropdown have more than 10 items

Tags: javafx

When I click for the first time in a ComboBox with more items (for example 8items), the scrollbar is shown at the right side (drop-down list have 8 items with scrollbar only one item visible i.e height of the dropdown list is suitable for one item). After I open it again, the scrollbar doesn't appear anymore and shows all the items.

problem in JRE8. its worked fine in JRE7.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Could you post your `ComboBox`? From the doc: "By default, when the popup list is showing, the maximum number of rows visible is 10", so I don't really understand why a scroll bar is appearing for you when you have 8 items. Also post OS and Java version please.

Comment: OS- Windows7. my combobox data fetched by async call. by callback method old data cleared and assigned new data items into combobox. like (dbListDropDown.getItems().clear();
dbListDropDown.getItems().addAll(dbList);)                                              dbListDropDown.setOnShown(new EventHandler<Event>()
  {
   @Override
   public void handle(Event event)
   {
    getComboboxItemList();
   }

Comment: first click the async call triggered then the height of the dropdown  calculated just before the data assigned to combobox because of this reason the first click the height of the dropdown is looks like default height. i.e single item height with scrollbar. in JRE7 JavaFx API handled  this scenario in ComboBoxListViewSkin (createListView method) but i think not in JRE8.

Comment: You could try to use `setOnShowing` rather than `setOnShown`. But this is quite strange design: isn't it possible to fill the combo by default and not on demand?

Comment: i tried setOnShowing also but same issue